# Is it possible to run a pruned node while being able to verify any TXID?

Tags: bitcoind

I am building a web app that implements bitcoin payments. My server has limited resources, and I don't want to fill up it's data with the ENTIRE blockchain (takes up too much space).

So I enabled pruning on bitcoind, and ran:

```
bitcoind -daemon -txindex
```

I got the error:

```
Error: Prune mode is incompatible with -txindex.
```

Is it not possible to verify any TXID I want with a pruned node? Is my only option to depend on a third party if I don't want to store the entire blockchain? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking two different things, so it's not clear which answer is correct.

Yes, a pruned full node verifies all transactions. That's why it's still called a full node.

No, pruning is not compatible with txindex.

But, are you sure you need txindex? If you're only receiving payments to yourself you don't need txindex.

Comment: D'oh! I'm not sure why I forgot pruned nodes can still verify payments received to it's own wallet. Thanks.

Comment: Not just to its own wallet, full nodes (including pruned ones) verify all payments, ever. That doesn't mean you can query them.